# How to get the preexisting models from mongoDB using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi i have an existing db by name test in mongoDB. In this db i have 3 models and one of them is by the name 'rentals'. How to retrieve all the data from that model using mongoose. Below is the code where i am creating connection and getting a client object

I tried different steps but none of them worked and i am getting error - Schema is not defined. Please help.

```
mongoose.connect(config.connection_string , {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).then((client)=>{

        /*client.model('rentals')*/
         /*client.collection("rentals").find({}).then(data=>{
            console.log(data)
         })*/
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose is **schema based**, Mongodb isn't.

The way to get the existing data with mongoose is to defined the model of the data inside of your code.

Example, if your data in database look like :

```
[{
  name: 'Foo',
}, {
  name: 'Bar',
  age: 55,
}, {
  carBrand: 'Toyota',
}]
```

1/ You can read all the data using a big mongoose schema :

```
{
  name: string,
  age: number,
  carBrand: string,
}
```

and you will get

```
[{
  name: 'Foo',
  age: undefined,
  carBrand: undefined,
}, {
  name: 'Bar',
  age: 55,
  carBrand: undefined,
}, {
  name: undefined,
  age: undefined,
  carBrand: 'Toyota',
}]
```

2/ You can read the targeted data, creating specific schemas

```
schemaA = {
  name: string,
}

schemaB = {
  name: string,
  age: number,
}

schemaC = {
  carBrand: string
}
```

If you do not want to create the models yourself, there are packages generating theses like [generate-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-schema)